# How to update Kafka config file with Docker IP address

Tags: macos, docker

I am running Kafka inside a Docker container. Kafka requires a connection to Zookeeper, and so I am running Zookeeper in another container. I am running Docker on OSX and so my VM has the IP address: `192.168.99.99`.

What I can't figure out, is how do I update my Kafka Docker installation to point to the instance of Zookeeper running inside its own separate Docker container, i.e. with IP address of `192.168.99.9` and port `2181`?

Kafka has a config file called `server.properties` which has a property of `zookeeper.connect` which I can set, but I want this value to be overridden dynamically, rather than hard-coding the IP here. How do I achieve this?

And, as an additional question, I want my Docker file to work across OS's - so whatever I do should work on Linux too..

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set an ip in that config file:

Through docker-compose v2 (docker 1.10+), a bridge network is created which means both containers are in that network and see each other.
See more at "[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)".

If Zookeeper expose its port 2181, the config file from Kafka can simply reference zookeeper by its container name.
And that will work on any docker (boot2docker on Mac or native docker on Linux)